# How to get alarms from Hikvision IPCamera

Tags: ip-camera

I have an Hikvision IP camera and I need to get alarm events produced by Line Crossing Detection to work with them from my Appweb.

Is there any way to request HTTP GET/POST method to send the alarms from the camera? Any way to get this information?

Any help will be great. Thank you in advanced.